# css/html Simple progress bar using hr tag

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I'm trying to make a simple progress bar using the width property of an HR representing percent complete. I did these years ago but for some reason I can't seem to make this one look right.  The website uses tables so I am placing the bar within a table cell.  I'm open to doing it with pure css but I would like this to be light as in a few lines of code as there is a lot of other stuff on this page that has to load quickly.

I can get the rule to display a nice solid bar.

```
<td width=200 style="border: 2px solid silver;padding:none"><hr style="color:#c00;background-color:#c00;height:15px; border:none;" align="left" width=50% /></td>
```

where the percentage complete is set on the server side with php.  This is not a dynamic bar where polling is required.  Just one that represents percentage of a profile that is complete.

Ideally, I'd like the bar to fill a percentage of the cell equal to that completed so that the solid bar shows what percent is done and the white space to the right what part remains.  However, I can't get a nice looking rule around the whole cell for the bar to fill a portion of.  Instead there is a lot of space around the bar.  I've tried setting the padding to none but that doesn't seem to work.

Here is a jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/GqrnC/

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Why use an `<hr>`? Just use a `<div>`, it will make life a lot easier.

Comment: Why do you want to use `<hr>`? You're clearly not using it for a "paragraph-level thematic break". I think you should something else (like a `<div>`).

Comment: What goes inside the div to show the bar?

Comment: Nothing, just set `width`, `height` and `background-color`.

Comment: oh.  nice.  anything special for different browsers or does that do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to remove the margins from the `<hr>` (add `margin: 0` to its styles) to get rid of the extra space: http://jsfiddle.net/GqrnC/1/

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width=200 style="border: 2px solid silver;padding:none">
      <hr style="color:#c00;background-color:#c00;height:15px; border:none;
                 margin:0;" align="left" width=50% />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, I agree with the comments above, I don't see any reason to use an `<hr>` instead of a `<div>` for this. The `<hr>` has the semantics of a "separator", which is not the case here. A div has neutral meaning.

Comment: That did it.  But how do you get the div to display a bar?  Don't you need to put something in it?

Comment: No, see the comment I just added on the question.

Answer (score 4):

Does this fit your needs better: http://jsfiddle.net/GqrnC/16/

You should really use `<div>` instead of a `<hr>` since a `<div>` is a structural element.

HTML

```
<div class='outer'>
    <div class='inner'>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer{
    border: 2px solid silver;
    width: 200px;
}
.inner{
    background-color: #c00;
    width: 50%;
    height: 5px;
}
```

Alternatively, I would recommend looking into the jQuery UI [progress bar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/).  It is built exactly for this case and looks really great (plus if you want to later, you can update it using AJAX).
​

Comment: Instead of `&nbsp;` you could use `height:Xpx` on `.inner`: http://jsfiddle.net/GqrnC/16/

Comment: Thanks!  Updated to reflect that.

Comment: since width of bar--here in css--is a dynamic variable, you would have to set it dynamically in the PHP.

Comment: Yes, it would be up to the author to decide whether they want to add a style attribute to the `<div>`, use js, or dynamically set it another way.